# Hop Analysis for Home Brewers - Interest Poll

Tags: beer, hops, alpha-acids, growing-hops, ibu

My future stepson is growing hops this coming season here in WA state. I'm a chemist and am thinking of doing the hop analysis for him. I'd like to poll you all and see if there is much interest in having your homegrown hops analyzed. Talked to two local brewing suppliers and they seemed to think that there is growing interest among their home growers in knowing what the IBU's are in their hops. If this seems to be true (interest is increasing), then I'll probably make the investment and get my own instrument for the analysis. Please let me know what you folk think. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's one vote to close as "not a real question".  I think there's obviously an implied questions here (beyond the let me know what you think bit), but I'd recommend editing this to include a specific call-to-action at the end.  Maybe something along the lines of: Is anyone else interested in having their hops' IBU levels analyzed?

Comment: I approve of trying to assist in providing a service to homebrewers, however that's really not what I think this site is trying to be.  "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face" -the FAQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been considering growing hops myself (in Madison, WI) and depending on how successful I am with that, I'd potentially be interested in having an analysis done.